# req.params changes between calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am writing a small node.js app on glitch.me and I have run into problem I don't really understand. It's kind of a message board (a project for freeCodeCamp), where you can post a thread (specifiyng a board) and then see the list of messages on the board. Threads are stored in mongodb collection. The name of the board is accessed through `req.params.board`. The problem is, `req.params.board` somehow gets 1 symbol shorter between two function calls. 
Here are my routing file and my handlers (in a separate module), and in handlers there are console.logs that will show you what I mean. Let's say we create a post on 'newBoard' board:

api.js

```
    module.exports = function (app) {

  app.route('/api/threads/:board')

  .get(threadHandler.getThreads)
  .post(threadHandler.postThread)
  .delete(threadHandler.deleteThread)
  .put(threadHandler.reportThread)

  app.route('/api/replies/:board')
  .post(threadHandler.postReply)
  .get(threadHandler.getReplies)
  .delete(threadHandler.deleteReply)
  .put(threadHandler.reportReply)

};
```

handlers:

```
  module.exports.postThread = function(req, res){
  console.log(req.params.board); //logs newBoard
  var newThread = new Thread({
    text: req.body.text,
    delete_password: req.body.delete_password,
    created_on: new Date(),
    bumped_on: new Date(),
    reported: false,
    replies: [],
    replycount: 0,
    board: req.params.board
  })
  newThread.save();
  res.redirect('/b/'+req.params.board);  
}

module.exports.getThreads = function(req, res){
//gets 10 last messages on the board
  console.log(req.params.board); //logs newBoar
  Thread.find({}).sort({bumped_on: -1}).limit(10).exec(function (err, docs){
    if (err) return;
    docs.forEach(function(doc)
     {
          if(doc.replies.length > 3) {
          doc.replies = doc.replies.slice(-3);
          }
          })
    res.json(docs);
  })
}
 module.exports.getReplies = function(req, res){
 //gets a separate thread with all the replies
  console.log(req.params.board, 'reply'); //logs newBoard + _id of the  thread, so the url is '/newBoard/5900d2da926ef6277e143564' it will log '/newBoard5900d2da926ef6277e143564', 'eating' the slash between board and id.

  Thread.findById(req.query.thread_id, function(err, foundThread){
    if (err) return;
    if (foundThread){
      res.json(foundThread);
    }
  })
}
```

I don't understand what's happening, so I'd be really grateful if somebody told me why does it happen and how to fix it. My whole project is here: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/shrouded-consonant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are redirecting to `/b/newBoard`, but [your HTML](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/shrouded-consonant?path=views/board.html:36:0) does this:

```
var currentBoard = window.location.pathname.slice(3,-1);
```

It assumes that the redirect is done to `/b/newBoard/`; with the `-1`, it's trying to slice the trailing slash, which doesn't exist. Hence `newBoar`.

The easiest solution is to fix the redirect:

```
res.redirect('/b/' + req.params.board + '/');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Redirect turned out to be only part of the problem, so I changed the slicing HTML to make it more foolproof (fool being myself in that case).